# How do I compare list with integers?

Tags: python, comparison-operators

This is the part of my code that I'm having trouble with.  for the part if nums >= -999 is not working.  i have tried int(nums) >= -999 too.  I'm not exactly sure how to fix this problem.  The error I get as the way the code is below is unorderable types: list() >= int()

```
from  statistics import mean
nums = [int(input("Enter Numbers ")) for _ in range(6)]
if nums >= -999:
    print("Sentinel value was entered")
print([x for x in nums if x > mean(nums)])
```

Comment: `nums` is a list. What are you trying to compare? Each item in the list?

Comment: what I'm trying to do is if a number enter is -999 or less than it prints out that message, and it does not work.

Comment: By "does not work" do you mean it asks for another number, or it just fails after all the numbers are entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do, but if you are trying to find out if there are any number >=-999 in the list, you could do:

```
too_large=[i for i in nums if i>=-999]
if (too_large):
    print("Sentinel value was entered")
```

This builds up a list (a subset of nums) where the number is >=-999, and puts it in too_large; then, if this list has any elements (`if (too_large):`) it prints the message.

Note that -999 is a very small number, many numbers (e.g. 1) are larger than this. I don't know if this was your intention.

Comment: Its not that I"m trying to find that. what I'm trying to do is if an user inputs -999,-1000, etc. on down it prints out "Sentinel value was entered"

Comment: @itsthewendigo: if you want "`-999` or less", then use this answer but with `<=` rather than the `>=` shown in this answer.

Comment: @AMADANON tweaked it a little, but same concept and it wokrs thanks for the help

Comment: @John1024 No, (s)he is using implicit boolean. An example discussion is https://peterman.is/blog/implicit-false-in-python/2013/01/

Comment: @jrennie I see.  That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to check if any of the numbers in a list is less than or equal to `-999`:

```
if any(x <= -999 for x in nums):
    # at least one of the numbers in nums was -999 or below
```